# No suitable driver found for jdbc Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Итак есть у меня проект который использует базу данных `mysql`. Когда заливаю файлы в томкат, при открытии соответствующей страницы вылетает exception:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learning?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

В web-inf jar файл mysql connector есть. В самой IDE все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, в вашем коде вы забыли зарегистрировать класс jdbc драйвера перед вызовом `DriverManager.getConnection()`

То есть надо сперва вызвать

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: хмм если мне память не изменят, то это требуется при использовании jdbc драйвера ниже версии 4.0 Начиная с 4.0 это автоматически делается

Comment: формально, возможно и так. Но в практике я встречал такое поведение в куче современных драйверов не только для MySql. Попробуйте зарегистрировать класс драйвера. Ошибка должна исчезнуть.

Comment: точно, спасибо.